# How to recreate activity by navigating from app notification?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, onbackpressed

I have recently implemented notifications for my application. What I have been testing is the behavior of how the application should work. I would imagine it would be something like this:

Notification is received and open `Comments.class` through intent -> `MainActivity.class` -> click back (exit application, go to home screen of Android device) -> reopen application through Task Manager -> Go back to `Comments.class`

The first few steps work but when I go from the task manager to open back up the application, I notice it goes to `Comments.class` which seems like expected behavior as I have tested with other Android applications.

However, some of the properties of my `Comments.class` are not being set and I know it is because the `onCreate` method of my `Comments.class` is not being called. Is there any reason why this wouldn't happen? This was my attempt:

`NotificationService.java`:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Comments.class);

Intent backIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
backIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


//Set a random notification Id for each notification so that if you get multiple, the first does not get replaced.
Random random = new Random();
int notificationId = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context, notificationId, new Intent[] { backIntent, resultIntent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
//When the notification is actually clicked on
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

This first creates the notification and notifies the user of the application. Then `Comments.java`'s `onCreate` function is called which is expected as I click on the `Notification`. Then, I click back which simply navigates back to `MainActivity` like so:

`Comment.java`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

Then, `MainActivity.java` is called and created which is all fine. If I click back on `MainActivity.java`, then I perform the following code:

Here's from `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Which takes me back to my device's home screen. However, an instance of my application is still running in the background and when I click on my application in the background and put it into the foreground, I am navigated back to `Comments.java` but because `Comments.java`'s `onCreate` method is not called, some of the details of the `Activity` is not initialized. Any idea why this is happening?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your initializations inside `onResume` function of your `Comment.java`. Here's a good read about [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) which may help you to understand the behaviour correctly.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // Your initialization
}
```